# How restart a stopped docker container

Tags: docker

I launch a docker container from an image with the following command:

```
$ docker run -d myimage /bin/bash -c "mycommand"
```

When `"mycommand"` is finished, the container is stopped (I suppose it is stopped), but it is not deleted, because I can see it with this command:

```
$ docker ps -a
```

Is there any way to `restart` this container with the same parameters and keep data generated by `mycommand`?

Comment: Does "volume" or "mounting a host directory" satisfying you? Like the doc mentioned: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Yes, when the initial command finish its execution then the container stops.

You can start a stopped container using:

`docker start container_name`

If you want to see the output of your command then you should add `-ai` options:

`docker start -ai container_name`

PS. there is a `docker restart container_name` but that is used to restart a running container - I believe that is not your case.

Comment: My container stops immediately after starting, each time. Not sure what the point of that is. Using the -ai command gives this response:
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Comment: @geoidesic could you please provide more details? What kind on 'requirements.txt' file you are talking about?

Comment: @geoidesic,  To troubleshoot this, I changed the entrypoint to simply run the sleep 900 command which allowed me to then connect to the container and run commands within it using ```docker exec -it container_name bash```.  When I ran the command from inside the container I could see why the initial implementation of my script was failing and I fixed it.

Comment: @PatS can you please share how you combined `start` with `sleep`? I'm unable to get to a point where I can run `exec`

Answer (score 26):

First, `$ docker ps -a` shows all containers (the ones that are running and the stopped ones), so that is the reason you are not seeing your stopped container listed.

Second, you can easily start a stopped container running:

```
$ docker start container_name
```

Once the container has been started, you can run your command by:

```
$ docker exec -it container_name bash -c "mycommand"
```

The stuff you create in your container will remain inside your container as long as it exists. If you want to keep data even if your container is removed you can use a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Answer (score 7):

It should be

```
$ docker restart container_id # OR
$ docker restart container_name
```

Comment: the accepted answer points out `restart` is for an already-running container

Answer (score 5):

[image]

From the above picture we see one container is up and other status is Exited.

When a container is exited we can still start it back up, because a container stop doesn't mean that it's like dead or cannot be used again we can very easily stop and then start containers again at some point in the future. To start a container backup we can take it's ID and then execute docker start and paste the ID end.

**sudo docker start  container_id**

command for exited container in the above picture will be.

**sudo docker start -a bba606a95392**

Out put:

[image]

**By the way:** While restarting a container we can not replace the default command, as soon as you started up with the default command is set for the container, for example if we start our container overriding the default command let's see what happened:

[image]

Docker is thinking we are trying to start and attach multiple container at the same time.

**So when we up a container and let it exit, we can start it back up again which is going to reissue the default command that was used when the container was first created. It is part of docker container lifecycle.**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you restart your VM/System and it shows

```
mysql-tls:5.7       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 hours ago   Exited (255) 44 seconds ago
```

Answer :

Start the Container

**docker start mysql**

or

**docker start your_container_name**

Answer (score 0):

## Pause/Restart Paused Container in Docker

### Version 23

#### 1. Get container ID

```
docker container ls
```

Copy **CONTAINER ID** from the output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
aeb64b607336   dbeaver/cloudbeaver:latest   "./run-server.sh"   About an hour ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8978/tcp   cloudbeaver
```

#### 2. Pause Container

```
docker container pause container_id
```

#### 3. Restart Paused Container

```
docker container unpause container_id
```