# How to reconnect to same postgres database on Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm very new to using docker and I've created a postgres container using
`docker run --name mytrainingdb -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres`. Then I connected to it with `docker exec -it <container-id> bash` and then `psql`.
Then I stop the container.

My query is, what do I do reconnect to the same database? I tried to run same docker run command, but it says the name 'mytrainingdb' is used, which means it is trying to create it afresh, which is not what I want. Hope my expectation is right, as in when I restart my laptop or resume work I can just restart the same container and my data/config would be preserved?

The documentation also mentions that we can link a host directory to volume of pg container to have the stored data accessible to us, but I'm ok with docker managing my storage for that database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have error when you try to re-run the same command, because docker is trying to create a new container with **same name as the previous one "mytrainingdb"**. If you close docker and reopen it you will still find your container , but its not running , you can start it again with  `docker start  mytrainingdb`  or you can remove it with `docker rm mytrainingdb`  .

However , dont restart docker because you want to create a new container with the same name! If you want to start a new container with the same name and your container is still running you can first stop it with `docker stop mytrainingdb` and `docker rm mytrainingdb` or you can just do `docker rm -f mytrainingdb`  (this will remove you running container with force ) and then create a new container..

As for the volumes ,you just **created** one by default which is named is kind of hash , and its found at volumes/var/lib/docker/volumes/ .Because generally containers such PostgreSQL, or databases in general  [persists volumes](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7bd41786539082857396f4d1b4f1cb326ebee8de/13/Dockerfile#L183). The volume gets created when running the container and is handy to save persistent data, whether you start the container with -v or not.

The volume you talked about in your question , is called mounted volume , is when you basically just bind a certain directory or file from the host (outside) to inside the container
docker run `-v /hostdir:/containerdir` in your case  `docker run -v /hostdir:/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Comment: Thanks, tried and it works! And yes, for my learning, I'm fine with internal management of storage. One query, suppose I forget the name mytrainingdb, can I see it listed somewhere in docker commands?

Comment: yes you can use  ````docker ps  -a ````  it will list all the existing containers (running or not)

Answer (score 1):

If you restart docker or your computer running containers won't be automatically restarted. You can start your container again with `docker start mytrainingdb` ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39689438/2178159)), then connect with your `docker exec` command.

(one tip: instead of running `bash`, then `psql`, you can directly run `psql`, e.g. `docker exec -it mytrainingdb psql --user postgres`)

Your understanding of data persistence is correct, docker will manage the data and it will still be around.

From the [`postgres` image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

> There are several ways to store data used by applications that run in Docker containers. We encourage users of the postgres images to familiarize themselves with the options available, including:
>
> - Let Docker manage the storage of your database data by writing the database files to disk on the host system using its own internal volume management. This is the default and is easy and fairly transparent to the user. The downside is that the files may be hard to locate for tools and applications that run directly on the host system, i.e. outside containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `--rm` argument so that whenever you stop the container manually, or container stops for any reasons (his task is done or it fails), it will remove that container.

In your case, you can use this:

```
docker run --name mytrainingdb --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```